# Let two table act as one

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, union

Is there any way to let two tables act as one? I have two identical tables, the only difference is that one contains recent data and the other one older data. Is there any way to do something like this?

```
select * 
  from customers a, 
       (rentals union archrentals) r
 where a.serno = r.custserno
   and r.rentaldate > YYYYMMDD;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a view like this?

```
CREATE VIEW v_allRentals
AS
SELECT * form rentals
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM archrentals
```

In this way you can use v_allRentals without worrying every time you create a query that you are forgetting the old ones.

Thanks,
Mucio

Comment: I guess this would mean that a completely new table is created? That doesn't work since we are talking of roughly 100 million of records. :-)

Comment: @user1297532 As long, as you won't create MATERIALIZED VIEW, there would be no new tables in DB, just a representation of existing data :) [read this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm)

Comment: sorry, I missed VIEW. No new table, just a view. Anyway with a properly partitioned table you shouldn't need to have an "archive" table for old records, also because you continue to query it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary table

```
select * 

INTO #allcustomers

  from customers a, 
       (rentals union archrentals) r
 where a.serno = r.custserno
   and r.rentaldate > YYYYMMDD;
```

then you can use the temptable to query the results.